# Inkscape Path Difference changing path size (turning bold/thin)

Tags: inkscape, path, bug

I've been using Inkscape for a few months, but recently, path difference hasn't been working like it has before.

The attached image is 2 identical logos on top of a black background, but the logo on the right is what I'm seeing when I go to "Path/Difference" (select right logo + black background, go to Path/Difference).

[image: Inkscape path difference, possible bug]

It's distorting the shape like a Bold effect. I've also seen the same thing happen with text, but the "Path/Difference" result has made the text much thinner.

I've had no problems with Path/Difference until recently. Any tips or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the green shape really a path? ( =the visible green area has all the object  has, there's nothing hidden and definitely there's no stroke) If not, convert it at first to a path - select it and apply Path > Object to Path.

Comment: The green shape has already been converted from a group to a path. Nothing is hidden and there's no stroke. Once I'd turned the logo into a path, I select the logo, then the rectangle behind, and go to Path > Difference and the issue above occurs

Comment: Can you share the file? I'm sure it can be fixed, but I don't even fully understand what you're doing without a file, as I don't know about the kinds of objects you have there.

Comment: Here's the svg file: https://we.tl/3al9bonhWK

Comment: There's a thick white stroke. Just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

The Stroke Size on the background rectangle is also applied anywhere there is path difference within the centre of the rectangle.

Problem resolved by removing Stroke from the background rectangle.